# Why do I get the error "CalendarService class not found" despite having the gdata-calendar-2.0.jar file?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have the `gdata-calendar-2.0.jar` file, but I get the error "CalendarService class not found".

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("example");
```

Comment: You should show the import statements you are using and a link to where you fetched the jar file from.

Comment: i attach jar file in reference library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the library in your project? You should place it in the libs\ folder of your project, and then in Eclipse you need to add it to the Java Build path. Right click on the project, goto properties, Java Build Path, then pick the libraries tab and add your Jar.

Comment: thanks for answer ...and now i attach jar file in lib folder but again same error occurs

Comment: if possible then tell me jar file name

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the name of the jar file is irrelevant. Once it's included in your java build path you can use it in your project by including the appropriate classes. Such as: `import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService;`